# Live Audio/Video Streaming and Encoding

Tags: java, android, iphone, h.264

I am newbie in Audio/Video streaming. I want to do some research on Streaming and Encoding. What should I take care before writing a piece of code?

I have following requirements:

1. Latency should be less then 1 second.
2. No Installation. Any alternative of Java Applet.
3. H.264 encoding.
4. No lagging.
5. Audio and Video should be in sync.
6. Protocol should be rtmp or http.
7. It should be working on Mac, PC and Linux plus mobile devices mainly iPhone and Android.

I know Java and Want to this in Java.

Comment: Take a look at [wowza](http://www.wowza.com/) or [red5](http://www.red5.org/).

Comment: Are you still working on this topic?